# Can't get SearchController to show with TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm following the raywenderlich.com tutorial to show a search bar for my table, but I can't see it anywhere (yes, I scrolled up)

[image: table at launch]
[image: after I scroll up]

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!        
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!)
    }

    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
      return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
      filteredStrings = stockArr.filter { (string: String) -> Bool in
        return string.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
      }
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
    var filteredStrings: [String] = []

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"

        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        
        definesPresentationContext = true
  
    }
}
```

Please help me, I've tried every StackOverflow solution and nothing works, this code didn't make a difference from the normal tableview I had before.

Comment: can you share the link which you are following?

Comment: @SMAbuTaherAsif https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using the `ViewController` without embedding it into a `UINavigationController`. You've to embed it in `UINavigationController` to make it show up in the `UINavigationBar`. So while using `ViewController` use it as follows, if you're using it programmatically.

```
UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
```

If the `ViewController` is created in storyboard then Use `Editor`-> `Embed In` -> `Navigation Controller`.

Comment: I haven't seen this as something you need for your view... Where do I put this code in my class?

Comment: You've probably created ViewController in storyboard so you can embed the ViewController in Navigation controller as mentioned above.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! My only other question is when I scroll up to reveal the search, and scroll down again, is there a way to hide it again?

Comment: Post the link here for me I'll surely take a look.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997798/hide-searchcontroller-again-after-scrolling-down

Comment: That was pretty quick. Will check it out.