# Hide SearchController again after scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, uisearchcontroller

I got SearchController to show up with my TableView, this is what is looks like on launch vs when I scroll up:

[image][image]

This is perfect since I want it hidden when not in use. However, after showing it, I can't hide it again by scrolling down. How do I get that functionality?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!        
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!)
    }

    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
      return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
      filteredStrings = stockArr.filter { (string: String) -> Bool in
        return string.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
      }
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
    var filteredStrings: [String] = []

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"

        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        
        definesPresentationContext = true
  
    }
}
```

Edit:

I played around with adding

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.title = "hello"
```

but it doesn't look like the normal SearchControllers out there (I don't get why I can't make it work like everyone else's seems to be working, it should automatically have this functionality based on what I saw on here http://blog.eppz.eu/swiftui-search-bar-in-the-navigation-bar/)

[image][image][image]

Comment: Don't forget to add the relevant code here. People seeing this post should be able to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to check for the scroll direction of `UITableView` and disable the `UISearchController` manually via code. Here's how:

```
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0 // declare the previous offset for reference

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) // remove let
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    //...
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    navigationItem.searchController = lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y ? nil : searchController
}
```

Comment: Inserted this code, but it crashes my project after I try scrolling down again. Is this functionality not included in the default SearchController?

Comment: You'd have to move the `searchController` declaration outside the function scope to the view controller's scope.

Comment: Yes, I have `var searchController : UISearchController!` outside of the viewDidLoad function

Comment: You're declaring a new searchController in viewDidLoad. Initialize the existing one and your issue is fixed. Just remove the `let`. Check my update if it's not clear.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't crash anymore, but unfortunately still doesn't hide the search after scrolling. It just bounces back as usual.

Comment: I've updated `scrollViewDidScroll` method. Check it out. It should work.

Comment: I tried it, didn't seem to work though. I'm confused because everywhere I look people already have this hiding functionality without making additional functions. I made an edit trying some new stuff as well.

Comment: I tried this code. It worked for me without any issues.

Comment: As a last resort, I've added 1 more line of code in `viewDidLoad` for you to modify.